# Buttons filling up available space, grouping them into a dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience

Say I have a top header of a view in the application. This header row should be single row, and contains action items like input boxes and/or action buttons. When I have, so to say, 5 action items in the header then on FHD resolution these doesn't take up the available horizontal space which is OK. Then on smaller screens, like an iPad (landscape, 1024px width) these action buttons, accumulated, have more width then the available. The generic responsive solution would be to wrap some items into a new row, right? Now in my case I can't wrap into multiple rows but what I need to achieve is to group those action items which doesn't have enough space into a dropdown.

How could I possibly identify which items doesn't have enough space so that which items I need to put into the dropdown? Is javascript the only solution? Is there a common way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to solve this would be using CSS media queries.

For example, the CSS tricks website uses this on their navbar: https://css-tricks.com/

You can see that on a desktop sized view there is a list of links on the left hand side of the page. But if you resize the page to be smaller this list of links collapses into a dropdown 'hamburger' style menu in the top navbar.

Read about media queries here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries.

Media queries basically allow you to add conditional rules based on screen size.

Comment: But what if I only want to include the outliers into the dropdown?